# Call `with`'s __exit__ Explicitly and Exit

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have class that opens a socket connection on initialization, and can transmit and receive certain messages back and forth with the counterparty.  I create an instance of the object using a `with` statement.  In my class, if I receive certain messages back on the socket, I want to explicitly close the connection, and exit the `with` statement.

I attempt to do so, by explicitly calling `self.\__exit__(None, None, None)`

```
def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    print 'Closing Connection'
    self.logout()
    self.conn.close()
    sys.exit(1)
```

However, I am finding that I am getting the `Closing Connection` message back twice, and running into problems because on the second call, there is no longer a connection to close.  Examining the code, I have ruled out all other instances of my explicit call to `self.__exit__(None, None, None)`.  What's going on?  Is the `sys.exit(1)` insufficient for preventing the `with` from garbage collecting again (although from what I've read, this seems to be the most "approved" way to do this)?  How do I prevent the `with` statement from calling `self.__exit__(None, None, None)`.  Any help, or a point in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `__exit__` method will always be called when control flow leaves the `with` statement, no matter how that happens. You shouldn't have to call it explicitly. It would be better if you restructured your code so you don't need to do this.

Comment: Also, having `sys.exit(1)` in an `__exit__` function is bad form. `__exit__` functions should only ever suppress exceptions or allow them to passthrough; they should not exit the program because they are only meant for cleanup or resource management. It hides program logic and makes your code hard to read. Run `sys.exit(1)` from within your top level `with` statement so it is clear you are exiting with an error value.

Comment: Don't explicitly call `__exit()__`, then there is no problem. You can return from inside the context manager, or you can fall off the end: this is how `__exit()__` should be invoked.

Comment: @eestrada, can you explain by what you mean by "Run `sys.exit(1) from within your top level `with` statement"?

Comment: @AmyD: Yes, although, since I can't do linebreaks in comments, it might be a bit hard to read. So instead of doing `with mycontext() as mc: if problem: mc.__exit__(None, None, None)` and having the `sys.exit(1)` live in your `__exit__` function, instead do `with mycontext() as mc: if problem: sys.exit(1)` and make it clear you are attempting to exit on failure. Your `__exit__` function will be called no matter how you leave your `with` statement (exception, exiting, falling of the end, early `return`, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are in a `with` statement, the only way to leave with without running `__exit__` is to use `os._exit`; that's bad. Instead, explicitly begin by calling `__enter__` if you want this behavior. Or change your class to make sure it doesn't do the cleanup twice if called twice like @Kay suggests in his answer. Or, do as @IsmailBadawi suggests in his comment, and refactor your code so you don't need to explicitly call `__exit__`.

Comment: When you say "explicitly begin by calling `__enter_`," do you mean not use the `with` statement? So, create the object.  Then call `obj.__enter__()`?

Comment: @AmyD: Yes, that is indeed what I mean by explicitly calling `__enter__`. However, this isn't something you should normally do. The only time I ever do it is as part of `setUp`/`tearDown` in unit testing (and even then only if there are no other options). Otherwise, let the `with` statement just do the work for you about when to call your `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions. All you need to worry about is how your `__exit__` function deals with exceptions, if it even needs to do so at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just memorize if the you already closed the connection / log / something:

```
class MyContext(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__already_closed = False

    ....

    def close(self):
        if not self.__already_closed:
            self.__already_closed = True
            self.logout()
            self.conn.close()

    def __exit__(...):
        self.close()
```

Maybe even add a "please don't cleanup" method:

```
    def do_not_cleanup(self):
        self.__already_closed = True
```